# NagiosXI return code of 126

Tags: nagios

Hey guys i have installed a new nagios XI installation using the vmware image. I am getting the following error

```
(Return code of 126 is out of bounds - plugin may not be executable)
```

This is showing on any monitoring device that tries to monitor port bandwidth.

I have this error showing up when i try and monitor both watch guard and cisco switches.

Any ideas which plugin/ plugin location would be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check whether the plugin has executable permissions. Doing some Google search I got this from the [nagios support forum](http://support.nagios.com/knowledgebase/faqs/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&catid=35&faq_id=17&expand=false&showdesc=true).

Comment: i saw that also earlier in my searches i just didn't think that would help. I figured a stock install of nagios xi using their vmware image would work... I guess that serves me well for assuming haha. Thanks!